# How to convert mySQL JSON column into javascript array?

Tags: javascript

DB JSON column data: `["admin", "leader", "manager"]`
javascript recieves: `[&quot;admin&quot;, &quot;leader&quot;, &quot;manager&quot;]`

What is the simplest way to create Javascript array?

Comment: Could you add an example of how you are retreiving the data from the database ?

Comment: @Nicolas It is Datatable render function:                 
targets: ['roles'], 
                render: function (data, type, row) {

https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.render

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just replace "&quot ;" to quotes and parse

```
const s = "[&quot;admin&quot;, &quot;leader&quot;, &quot;manager&quot;]"
const obj = JSON.parse(s.replace(/&quot;/g, "\"")))
```

but better check why do you receive data in such format

Comment: It works! Thank you! Appreciate your support! Wish you good year and a lot of profitable projects!

Comment: Hahaha, happiness is enough, i dont run for profit.